# Need Multi threading environment to run single test case i.e need to run single test case on multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have Unit Test cases written for wcf services. Now i need to run single test case on multiple threads to check performance. i.e if that particular method is called by multiple users(needs to be a custom no. ie. any number from 20 - 500). How can i achieve this ?
I have gone through the [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Task Prallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But not able to get anything fruitful for my requirement.

Comment: Why not using JMeter or HPLoadRunner ?These softwares are designed to perform this kind of tests.

Comment: tazyDevel i need to perform this testing through coding and not using any tool..:) anyway thanks for your response.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... Hope this helps...

To run a method in other Thread, simply do:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => YourMethodName()).Start();
```

This can be used multiple times.

Note that this method returns void and does not receive any parameters.

To achieve what you want, you need to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++)
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(() => YourMethodName()).Start();
}
```

Notes:

a) With this code, you dont know when a thread will end. To verify when a thread is finished, you need to use the .IsAlive property. Example:

```
Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => YourMethodName());
t.Start();
```

To verify:

```
if (t.IsAlive)
{
      // running
}
else
{
     // finished
}
```

2) Exceptions cannot be handled from outside. You need to handle all the exceptions inside the thread, otherwise the program will break if an exception is raised.

3) You can't access UI elements inside the thread. To access the UI elements, you will need to use the Dispatcher.

**Edit**

You can do more things in other thread than just firing a method.

You can pass parameters:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => YourMethodName(a, b, c)).Start();
```

You can run more than a single method:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => 
{
     YourMethodName(a, b, c);
     OtherMethod(a);         
}).Start();
```

And you can receive values returned from the thread:

```
int x = 0;
new System.Threading.Thread(() => { x = YourMethodName(); }).Start();
```

To know when the x receive the value from the thread, you can do (lets suppose an int):

```
int x 
{ 
    set { VariableSetted(value); }  // fire the method
}  // put it in global scope, outside the method body
```

and

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => { x = YourMethodName(); }).Start();
```

and a method to run when the thread has returned the value:

```
public void VariableSetted(int x)
{
     // Do what you want with the value returned from thread
     // Note that the thread started this method, so if you need to
     // update UI objects, you need to use the dispatcher.
}
```

I don't know if you are using WPF to make the UI, but if is, to update the screen you can do this:

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => 
{ 
    string result = YourMethodName(); 
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { yourTextBox.Text = result; }));
}).Start();
```

You can also start nested threads (thread inside thread).

Comment: When trying to perform load testing, you should also consider adding some kind of additional wait-time (fixed or random) between your multiple tests. In most cases firing 500 calls from a simple loop isn't likely going to be a production like scenario.

Comment: I think that this depends on the time that each call need to complete. If these calls are fast, then is better to fire as fast as you can, to ensure that all calls will be running at same time. This is the objective of load testing, isn't?

Comment: I assume he is trying to emulate 500 simultaneous users. In most cases no 500 users within a company hit the enter key within lets say less than a second. In my experience this kind of unrealistic stress testing only leads to false interpretation of results trying to optimize code mostly not necessary

Comment: @tazyDevel You are right, but maybe the calls are slow (like making a select into a gigabyte table) and have great chance to run at same time in the real word. Again, maybe this makes sense.

Comment: Guilherme: Thanks for your response.. :) I just wanted to ask if "() => YourMethodName()" can accept method with parameters ?? i.e rather than YourMethodNAme() can i have something like YourMethodName(i,j)..??

Comment: @Gulliherme: Thanks you very much.. Worked perfectly.. :).. Sry I cannot upvote your Answer i have only 2 reputation.. at least 15 is required.. :(